# PDF signing with timestamp: certificate details does not appear in timestamp properties

Tags: itext, digital-signature, trusted-timestamp, rfc3161

I have a code that implements TSA server in format RFC 3161.
When I try to sign PDF file with timestamp using TSAClientBouncyCastle, I receive a signature where certificate details doesn't appear

[image]

Somebody know how to solve that?

I can post the code here, but I don't know which part of it. 
It would be nice if someone could guide me to a specific section in the RFC, then I will post the relevant part of the code and we can discuss about it.
Thanks in advance

Link to sample pdf file
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B61KdyZ43x-9cEk5YVV6WVd4WUU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Please share a sample PDF timestamped by your code for analysis.

Comment: I added link to my main message. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why certain timestamp authority details do not appear is indicated in the *Signature Properties* dialog beneath the *Advanced Signature Properties* dialog you have in front in your screenshot:

[image: The signature includes an embedded timestamp but it is invalid.]

Thus, you do not only have to inspect your PDF signing code but also your *code that implements TSA server in format RFC 3161* or the certificates it uses.

**The TSA certificate**

Your TSA certificate is invalid.

Digging through your signature, I eventually had a look at the certificates. As it turns out, you seem to use the same certificate for signing the signature and the time stamp. This cannot work!

Cf the specification:

> The TSA MUST sign each time-stamp message with a key reserved
> specifically for that purpose.  A TSA MAY have distinct private keys,
> e.g., to accommodate different policies, different algorithms,
> different private key sizes or to increase the performance.  The
> corresponding certificate MUST contain only one instance of the
> extended key usage field extension as defined in [RFC2459] Section
> 4.2.1.13 with KeyPurposeID having value:

> ```
> id-kp-timeStamping.  This extension MUST be critical.
> ```

> *([Section 2.3.* Identification of the TSA *of RFC3161](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3161#section-2.3))*

Your user certificate in particular does not have the required extended key usage marking it as a time stamping certificate.

Comment: when I changed the certificate to another one with time stamping key usage, it works! thanks alot

Comment: Unfortunately I am stuck again with a more difficult problem. I try to sign with certificate created by my PKI department, it contains id-kp-timeStamping as required, but I have a same problem. I attach the example of bad signed pdf [link](http://jiom.org.il/files/badSignedPDF.pdf). Is it possible to have a look, what is wrong?

Comment: @AGDev It contains the extended key usage extension with value `id-kp-timeStamping` but it is not marked critical. See above, for time stamping purposes it must be marked critical.

Comment: You are right. I missed it, now it works. Thank you!